# Why can't I pass api params to lambda function?

Tags: node.js, lambda, api-gateway

I am trying to setup an api gateway to simply send and email via lambda and was ses.

```
var aws = require('aws-sdk');
var ses = new aws.SES({
   region: 'us-east-1'
});
const querystring = require('querystring');
const inspect = require('util').inspect;


exports.handler = function(event, context) {
    var output = querystring.parse(event);
    console.log("Incoming: ", output["email"]);
    email=output["email"]

    console.log("Incoming: ", email);
    var eParams = {
        Destination: {
            ToAddresses: [email]
        },
        Message: {
            Body: {
                Text: {
                    Data: "some trial text"
                }
            },
            Subject: {
                Data: "Email Subject!!!"
            }
        },
        Source: "info@ayyy.com"
    };

    console.log('===SENDING EMAIL===');
    var email = ses.sendEmail(eParams, function(err, data){
        if(err) console.log(err);
        else {
            console.log("===EMAIL SENT===");
            console.log(data);


            console.log("EMAIL CODE END");
            console.log('EMAIL: ', email);
            context.succeed(event);

        }
    });

};
```

Lambda code looks like this. How do I get the event data passed on from api?

The console log looks like this:

```

```

14:00:57
START RequestId: f07a7595-3034-11e8-81c7-d3dcc4528819 Version: $LATEST
START RequestId: f07a7595-3034-11e8-81c7-d3dcc4528819 Version: $LATEST

14:00:57
2018-03-25T14:00:57.195Z    f07a7595-3034-11e8-81c7-d3dcc4528819    Incoming: undefined
2018-03-25T14:00:57.195Z    f07a7595-3034-11e8-81c7-d3dcc4528819    Incoming: undefined

14:00:57
2018-03-25T14:00:57.232Z    f07a7595-3034-11e8-81c7-d3dcc4528819    Incoming: undefined
2018-03-25T14:00:57.232Z    f07a7595-3034-11e8-81c7-d3dcc4528819    Incoming: undefined

14:00:57
2018-03-25T14:00:57.232Z    f07a7595-3034-11e8-81c7-d3dcc4528819    ===SENDING EMAIL===
2018-03-25T14:00:57.232Z    f07a7595-3034-11e8-81c7-d3dcc4528819    ===SENDING EMAIL===

14:00:58
2018-03-25T14:00:58.095Z    f07a7595-3034-11e8-81c7-d3dcc4528819    { [ValidationError: 1 validation error detected: Value null at 'destination' failed to satisfy constraint: Member must not be null] message: '1 validation error detected: Value null at \'destination\' failed to satisfy constraint: Member must not be null', code: 'ValidationError', time: Sun Mar 25 2018 14:00:58 GMT+0000 (UTC), r
2018-03-25T14:00:58.095Z    f07a7595-3034-11e8-81c7-d3dcc4528819    { [ValidationError: 1 validation error detected: Value null at 'destination' failed to satisfy constraint: Member must not be null]
message: '1 validation error detected: Value null at \'destination\' failed to satisfy constraint: Member must not be null',
code: 'ValidationError',
time: Sun Mar 25 2018 14:00:58 GMT+0000 (UTC),
requestId: 'f14b32f1-3034-11e8-897b-633b17ff4491',
statusCode: 400,
retryable: false,
retryDelay: 54.40075590740889 }

14:00:58
END RequestId: f07a7595-3034-11e8-81c7-d3dcc4528819
END RequestId: f07a7595-3034-11e8-81c7-d3dcc4528819

14:00:58
REPORT RequestId: f07a7595-3034-11e8-81c7-d3dcc4528819  Duration: 1498.93 ms    Billed Duration: 1500 ms Memory Size: 128 MB    Max Memory Used: 37 MB

Answer (score 1):

Log the event and see how it is structured. Your function fails from the start as the email is undefined. In API Gateway, if you defined `LAMBDA PROXY INTEGRATION`, your event body will be structured like this:

```
{
  "message": "Good day, John of Seattle. Happy Friday!",
  "input": {
    "resource": "/{proxy+}",
    "path": "/Seattle",
    "httpMethod": "POST",
    "headers": {
      "day": "Friday"
    },
    "queryStringParameters": {
      "time": "morning"
    },
    "pathParameters": {
      "proxy": "Seattle"
    },
    "stageVariables": null,
    "requestContext": {
      "path": "/{proxy+}",
      "accountId": "123456789012",
      "resourceId": "nl9h80",
      "stage": "test-invoke-stage",
      "requestId": "test-invoke-request",
       ... 
      },
      "resourcePath": "/{proxy+}",
      "httpMethod": "POST",
      "apiId": "r275xc9bmd"
    },
    "body": "{ \"callerName\": \"John\" }",
    "isBase64Encoded": false
  }
}
```

You want to read the queryStringParameters Object.

Answer (score 0):

Ok. I figured out the problem. Needed to parse JSOn with JSON.parse and then it worked.